# Getting maximum values from a table column, for associated id's from another column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to grab the maximum spend_price for each supplier_id from a minimums table. Each supplier has multiple spend prices and I can't seem to find an effective query to pull out the maximum spend_price for each one.

I've tried ordering and grouping but it seems like a very convoluted approach

```
min = Minimum.where(supplier_profile_id: [10005, 100010])
```

```
min.order(spend_price: :desc, supplier_profile_id: 
   :desc).group_by(&:supplier_profile_id)
```

```
min.each do |key, value|
                        max_spend_prices << [key, value[0].spend_price]
                    end
```

Comment: can you post the actual model relations?  what is a `spend_price` ? is it a model with a `belongs_to :minimum` relation?

Comment: spend_price is a column in the minimum table, the supplier_profile_id is a column in the minimum table as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
Minimum
  .where(supplier_profile_id: [10005, 100010])
  .group(:supplier_profile_id)
  .maximum(:spend_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
Minimum.group(:supplier_profile_id).maximum(:spend_price)
```